# Button and text is not in line

Tags: html, css, layout

does anybody know why the button on the right isn't in line with the title and the Button on the left? I tried it with position:fixed, but then it's under the title (visible but not clickable). I don't now what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    <header class="title">

  <button id="buttonLeft" class="btn-square pull-left" onclick="toggleMenu()">

    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>

  </button>

  <div id="headerElements">

    <h1> TITEL </h1>

  </div>

  <button id="buttonRight" class="btn-square pull-right" onclick="">

    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>

  </button>

</header>

  header.title {

  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #37baf4;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 90;
}

header h1 {

  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 90;
}

#buttonLeft {
  float: left;
  margin: 18px;
  z-index: 101;
}

#buttonRight {

  float: right;
  margin: 18px;
  z-index: 101;
}

.pull-left {}

.pull-right {}

.btn-square {

  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white;
}
```

Thanks
[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/67jysh83/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header.title {

  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #37baf4;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 90;
}
header.title  div{
  float: left;
}

header h1 {

  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 90;
}

#buttonLeft {
  float: left;
  margin: 18px;
  z-index: 101;
}

#buttonRight {

  float: right;
  margin: 18px;
  z-index: 101;
}

.pull-left {}

.pull-right {}

.btn-square {

  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="title">
  <div>
    <button id="buttonLeft" class="btn-square pull-left" onclick="toggleMenu()">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="headerElements">
    <h1> TITEL </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="buttonRight" class="btn-square pull-right" onclick="">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>
  </div> 
</header>
```

The width of the each  `div`  in  `.titlle`  is dependent of your choice.

Comment: @Adrian, can you click on the "This answer is use full" button, if you don't mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elements that displays like block.
Div and h1.

```
 <div id="headerElements">

    <h1> TITEL </h1>

  </div>
```

And in style h1 you used **width: 100%**

```
header h1 {

  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 90;
}
```

You need delete **div id="headerElements"** and replace h1 style to

```
header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't let yourself get misleaded by Float:right.

You should do by example:

```
#buttonLeft{
     width:20%;
     float:left;
}
#headerElements{
     width:60%;
     float:left;
}
#buttonRight{
     width:20%;
     float:left;
}
```

They shovel left towards eachother, that will do the trick ;)